# Как передать значение в Hub через консоль или через контроллер. SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Мне нужно, чтобы я мог отправить сообщение через консоль. Я пробовал отправлять `POST` запрос со значениями user и message, а затем вызывать метод Hub напрямую, но это результата не дало. Ошибка с `null`. Вот код, который я использовал

Так отправляю `POST` запрос:

```cs
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44395");
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user", "10"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("message", "3")
});
var result1 = await client.PostAsync("/Home/Area", content);
string resultContent1 = await result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(resultContent1);
```

Он работает, все хорошо.

Сам `Controller`:

```cs
public async Task<string> Area(string user, string message)
{
    ChatHub ch = new ChatHub();
    return $"{ch.SendMessage(user, message)}";
}
```

Hub:

```cs
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

Наверняка можно сразу на `Hub` отправить как-то, но я вообще не нашел об этом никакой информации...

**Что мне нужно:** Отправить через консоль сообщение на Hub, которое разошлется всем клиентам.

Comment: Я бы советовал для обмена данными использовать json вместо form-urlencoded, ну это потом, как все заработает. Для начала попробуйте полученный POST хотя-бы в логи записать.

Comment: POST запрос выполняется и возвращает значение, если не выполнять ChatHub. Отправил user и message и вернул назад тоже самое. Так что значения передаются правильные, я даже проверял каждое поле на null, и если null, то не выполнял. Ничего это не дало. Какое-то непонятное значение триггерит null exception.

Comment: Запишите в лог `user` и `message`. Убедитесь, что вы их получили корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Пришлось покопаться в англоязычных статьях и наконец нашел то, что мне нужно!

Hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

`Controller`:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/broadcast")]
public class BroadcastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _hub;
    
    public BroadcastController(IHubContext<ChatHub> hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get(string user, string message)
    {
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
        ...
    }

...

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
        ...
    });
}
```

index.cshtml:

```
@page
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">User</div>
        <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="userInput" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">Message</div>
        <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="messageInput" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

chat.js:

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Теперь перейдем, собственно, к консоли.

Устанавливаем соединение к Hub через консоль вот так:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:18128/ChatHub")
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        await connection.StartAsync();
        string message = Console.ReadLine();
        await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "Console", message);
    }
}
```

**Примечание:**

Может быть ошибка связанная с тем, что у класса `HubConnectionBuilder` нету метода `WithUrl`. Это связано с тем, что Visual Studio установил вам лишние библиотеки и связал класс `HubConnectionBuilder` с `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core` (если вы устанавливали через "показать возможные решения", то Visual Studio установит вам обе библиотеки Client.Core и Client) Рекомендую установить вручную `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` и подключить вот так `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;`.